# How to open meteor files in texteditor

Tags: meteor

Where can i find the meteor files?

I followed the following steps:

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
Create a project:

$ meteor create myapp
Run it locally:

$ cd myapp
$ meteor
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

open sublime, try to find my project, but its nowhere to be found.

I'm probably missing something somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Rick

Comment: The app will be located in the folder `myapp` inside whatever folder you were in when you opened the terminal or ran `meteor create myapp`.

Comment: i think that would be my root dir  /bin/myapp
but in my finder i can't find that folder.

Comment: found it by cmd + shift + g and then /bin/myapp. Still no idea how to navigate to this place though :)

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS Finder Graphical UI does not normally show directories (Folders) like `/bin` and other unix specific parts of the operating system. It does provide a method for accessing these directories by using the Go->Go to Folder menu option allowing you to type in the `/bin/myapp` path as you have discovered.

You can also navigate there using terminal: `cd /bin/myapp`, type `ls`, and hit the return key to see a directory listing of your files in this sub directory. You could then use `sudo nano` to edit the files you would like to change from the command line.

`sudo` will ask you for your user password and is only required if you do not have permissions set to allow you to change the file to be edited

You might want to try the free app [TextWrangler by Barebones](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), since it has a check box in its File->Open dialog that allows you to see hidden subdirectories and navigate through them in a graphical UI.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ASGM will follow your lead